# How to refresh / update pageMod contentScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

Is it possible to update it using an interval? I have tried:

```
var timers = require("timers");
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
var mystyle = ....;

function func1(){
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.org",
  contentScript: mystyle
});
}
func1();

function func2(){
   mysyle = http://......
}

timers.setInterval(func2,10000);
```

The problem is that it will start registering pageMod couple of times every interval.
Let's say I have inside of mystyle: alert("hello world"); so I'll go to to some page, after 30 seconds it when I'll refresh that single page it will execute 3 times "hello world" inside of alert box. I want it to execute only once  and updateing the mystle every 30 seoncds.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly change the `contentScript` property if you save the page-mod

First create your page-mod and save the object in a variable, like `mod` below.  Then on your interval you can alter the `contentScript` property like you see in the `func2`.  Once you've altered the `contentScript` you'll need the page-mod to re-evaluate the page somehow, I used a page reload since it sounded like from your description that was already happening.

```
var mod = require("page-mod").PageMod({
  include: ["*.org"],
  contentScript: "alert('the first alert');"
});

function func2(){
  // change the contentScript
  mod.contentScript = "alert('the second alert');";
  // cause the page-mod to re-evaluate
  require("tabs").activeTab.reload();
}

tab = require("tabs").open("http://mozilla.org");
require("timers").setInterval(func2, 5 * 1000);
```